# Can I / How do I use Postman to connect to an MLAB DB?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, postman

maybe I'm totally misunderstanding this.  I have a dB both locally and on MLAB,  I've connected to the Mlab DB with Robo3T so I see the db is there and there are 4 collections, one of them has fake products.

If I'm in Postman, and I'm using a GET http://localhost:8080/products/
content-Type application/json

it returns the correct response 3 items.

When I try to do the same Get request to my Mlab at:

GET mongodb://standarduser:thinkuser1@ds141613.mlab.com:41613/grocerycompanion/products/

I'm getting:  Could not get any response:

There was an error connecting to mongodb://standarduser:thinkuser1@ds141613.mlab.com:41613/grocerycompanion/products/.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You really should not post your username and password in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postman can't just use the mongo protocol `mongodb://`, you will need to build a REST api in front of your mLab database, then query it with postman, you can take some inspirations [here](https://programmerblog.net/nodejs-mongodb-rest-api/)

Or, if you just want to see the data inside, consider using [MongoDB Compass](https://www.mongodb.com/products/compass).

[image: Connect like this]

Comment: Thanks I understand better now, so basically I "think" I would need to just deploy this to like heroku and use postman on the API from there, not straight to the database.

All still new to me, thanks for the explanation.